# D3.js collapsible tree - Expand up to depth-level 2 or 3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

Currently I'm working with collapsible tree (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) which when first called expand up to depth-level 1. That means

```
Case:1
   2
  /
 1--3
  \
   4
```

My tree sometimes looks like that and sometimes may look like the following:

```
Case:2    
      3
     /
 1--2--4
     \
      5
```

and sometimes may look like the following:

```
Case:3    
         4
        /
 1--2--3--5
        \
         6
```

Case-1 is fine for me. My problem is when case-2 and case 3 tree is created, I see something like the following:

```
    1--2
```

I have to then click on node-2 to expand further. What I want is: if the root node has only 1 child node, then the child node should also be expanded to its children (as shown in case:2) and if that child node has only 1 child too, it should expand to till its children (case:3). How can I achieve this? Any hint or suggestion would help me a lot.

Comment: please check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754273/d3-js-tree-expand-all-and-collapse-all

Comment: Hi Cyril, Thanks for your comment. I have already checked that. But I don't want to expand all the nodes at the same time. I want to control when to expand till which level depending on data. Could you please help me achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

To get the 1 — 2 example above your code would look like:

```
root.children.forEach(collapse);
```

To collapse things after the second level - i.e. you will only display the root and the children at the first level.

If you want to start with the next level down you would amend that to:

```
root.children[0].children.forEach(collapse);
```

For the root plus two levels.

Hope that helps